# Testing event-driven architecture

Tags: java, soa, distributed, microservices, event-driven-design

I would like to ask, is there any guidance to test event driven architecture.

What I mean is to create automatic test, which will check, if events spawned by Service A, can still be consumed by Service B.

I know there is Pacto for Rest communication, but what about event?